# Is the logarithm twice differentiable?

Tags: differential

$f(x) = \ln (x)$ and $f''(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2}$.

However, when $x=0$, $f''(0)=-\infty$.

Does $f(x)$ twice differentiable?

Comment: $f$ itself is not even defined at $x=0$, so it can't be differentiable there.

Comment: Note that $f(x) = \ln x$ is not even defined at $x=0$.  However it is differentiable twice (and any number of times) at values $x$ where the logarithm is defined.

Comment: thanks @hardmath. So, the differentiability of a function has a relationship to the domain of that function. thanks.

Comment: It is not defined at $x=0$, so you would not say that it is differentiable or it is not differentiable at that point.  An old professor of mine said that it's like asking whether or not $\ln x$ is differentiable at the San Diego Zoo :)

Comment: It’s a fault of mathematics instruction in US high-schools that the importance of the *domain* of a function is not emphasized at all, sometimes not even mentioned. We can’t speak of differentiability of a function where it’s not defined, and we can’t speak of continuity of a function where it’s not defined, either. This leads to the lie that almost all high-school texts push, that the reciprocal function $f(x)=1/x$ is discontinuous at zero. It’s true that $0$ is a *singularity* of this function, but not a *discontinuity*, because the function is not defined at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is infinitely differentiable. Just only for positive arguments.